# Ramda, concat with propOr/pathOr

Tags: ramda.js

```
const obj = {
  psets: [...],
  type: {
   psets: [...]
  }
}
```

Want to concat the `psets` props. Both of them may not exist.

```
R.concat(R.pathOr([], ['type','pSets']), R.propOr([], 'pSets'));
```

**

```
Uncaught TypeError: function n(r){return 0===arguments.length||w(r)?n:t.apply(this,arguments)} does not have a method named "concat"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.concat expects arrays or strings, and not functions. You can use R.converge to prepare the arrays for concat.

Note: R.__ is used as a placeholder for incoming arguments that you to assign to a different position than the last parameter.

```js
const obj = {
  pSets: [1, 2],
  type: {
   pSets: [3, 4]
  }
}

const fn = R.converge(R.concat, [
  R.pathOr([], ['type','pSets']), 
  R.propOr([], 'pSets')]
)

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Another option that will make the code DRYer is to use R.chain to iterate the paths, get the the values from the object, and concat them:

```js
const obj = {
  pSets: [1, 2],
  type: {
   pSets: [3, 4]
  }
}

const fn = R.curry((paths, obj) => R.chain(R.pathOr([], R.__, obj), paths))

const result = fn([['pSets'], ['type','pSets']], obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Much of the time, `lift` is a nice alternative to `converge`:  `lift(concat)(pathOr(...), propOr(...))`.  It a more standard function than the Ramda-specific `converge`.  It is less flexible, but I would choose it when it works.